# How do I predict the next sequence in this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, trees

After naming the nodes of a Binomial expanding tree as follows: [image]

I want to find a way to sequentially iterate through the nodes of a tree with this structure, but one with indefinite branch lengths.

What formula can I use (Algebraically or in Code) to determine the name of the next node in this sequence, based only on the name of the previous Node.

Here is the start of the sequence of Node Names:

[0], [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QejeB.jpg)], [2], [1,1], [3], [2,1], [1,2], [1,1,1], [4], [3,1], [2,2], [1,3], [2,1,1], [1,2,1], [1,1,2], [1,1,1,1], [5], [4,1], [3,2], [2,3], [1,4], [3,1,1] ...

What I have so far:

If all values in the name of the previous node equal 1, then the next node name equal one value equal to the sum of the values of the previous node, plus one.

Examples: [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QejeB.jpg)] => [2], [1,1,1] => [4]

If all values, except the last one, in the name of the previous node equal 1, then the next node name starts with the sum of the values of the previous node minus the amount of values in the previous node name. This starting number is then followed by ones until the sum of this node name equals the sum of the previous node.

Examples: [3] => [2,1], [1,1,3] => [2,1,1,1], [6] => [5,1], [1,4] => [3,1,1]

Now I am stuck the remaining node names.

Note: The amount of values (Length) and the sum of the values (Total) of these node names do not change as you move from the previous node to the next one, you only iterate through the possible permutations.

Comment: $1$ is expanded down while $1111$ is expanded left. If iterations and expansions are not handled the same way, you don't know before the access the type of next cell you will find. Somewhere, the graph must contain informations that would be redundant with an another design

Comment: Igael, the way I structured the graph was by viewing a straight continuation of a branch as an increase in the trailing number, but a bend would result in a side branch and thus adding an additional value at the end of the Node Name. So the longer the Node Name the further down some path of side branches the Node resides. However, the actual direction (left right, up, down) is unimportant, it is just a way to better visually grasp the sequence.

Comment: As far I know, the graph is just equivalent to the structure of the datas, which is primarily scalar. If you change the graph conventions, you change also the other conventions of data handling. In a common graph, if you follow your vector , you see brothers and sisters and if you change of vector you get the one of daughters and sons ( or mother ). If I take the graph litteraly, I don't always know if I am on the same vector or if I jumped to a parent other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the sequence you have given, but close:

$$
\operatorname{next}\big((a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1})\big) = 
\Big(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{k-2}, a_{k-1} - 1, 1+\sum_{i = k}^{n-1} a_i\Big)
$$
where $$k = \min\Big\{j \in \mathbb{N} \ \Big|\ \forall i \in \{j,\ldots,n-1\}.\ a_i = 1 \Big\} $$
under convention in which sequences 
\begin{align}
&(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{k-2}) \\
&(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{k-1}, a_{k-1}-1) \\
\end{align} and set $\{j, \ldots, n-1\}$ are empty for $k=1$, $k=0$ and $j > n-1$ respectively.

Starting from $(1)$ we get following tuples:
\begin{align}
&(1) \\
&(2) \\
& &&(1, 1) \\
&(3) \\
& &&(2, 1) \\
& &&(1, 2) &&(1, 1, 1) \\
&(4) \\
& &&(3, 1) \\
& &&(2, 2) &&(2, 1, 1) \\
& &&(1, 3) &&(1, 2, 1) &&(1, 1, 2) &&(1, 1, 1, 1) \\
&(5) \\
& &&(4, 1) \\
& &&(3, 2) &&(3, 1, 1) \\
& &&(2, 3) &&(2, 2, 1) &&(2, 1, 2) &&(2, 1, 1, 1) \\
& &&(1, 4) &&(1, 3, 1) &&(1, 2, 2) &&(1, 2, 1, 1) &&(1, 1, 3) \\
& &&       &&(1, 1, 2, 1) &&(1, 1, 1, 2) &&(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
\end{align}

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much! Mr dtdarek is are most kind :)